# How do you update the properties of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How do you update the properties of an object in javascript?
I would to update "id" of 68917 distance from 8.8 to 4.5...
I have access to lodash.js

```
[
      {
        "_id":68917,
        "Distance":8.81,
        "Lat":"42.65322175",
        "Lon":"-73.77398886"
      },
      {
        "_id":131277,
        "Distance":"9.86",
        "Lat":"42.654658",
        "Lon":"-73.805866"
      },
      {
        "_id":62450,
        "Distance":6.58,
        "Lat":"42.67457566",
        "Lon":"-73.74902171"
      }]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
your_object[0].Distance = 4.5;
```

If you don't know the index beforehand:

```
_.findWhere(your_object, {'_id': 68917}).Distance = 4.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided provides an array. If this is is representative of your code, you can then iterate over the objects in the array using a for loop:

If you assign the provided code to a variable named array, you can use this code to iterate over the items in the array.

Once you do that, you can then access the properties of the objects inside using the dot operator, locating and updating the correct item.

```
function echo (text){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text + "<br/>"
}


var array = [
  {
    "_id":68917,
    "Distance":8.81,
    "Lat":"42.65322175",
    "Lon":"-73.77398886"
  },
  {
    "_id":131277,
    "Distance":"9.86",
    "Lat":"42.654658",
    "Lon":"-73.805866"
  },
  {
    "_id":62450,
    "Distance":6.58,
    "Lat":"42.67457566",
    "Lon":"-73.74902171"
  }];


echo("First item's distance " + array[0].Distance);

for(var i = 0; i < array.length;  i++){
    if(array[i]._id === 68917){
        echo("Found item "+array[i]._id);
        array[i].Distance = 4.45;
    }
}

echo("First item's distance " + array[0].Distance);
```

I created a JS Fiddle that demonstrates this solution works;
http://jsfiddle.net/gB5Nn/2/

Comment: Can you put the iterator before the ending condition in a JS for loop?

Comment: Nope, I made a syntax error. I rely on my IDE far too much.
In any case, the _lodash answer since provided by ch2500 will be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in "filter" function to get the item you want.

```
someObject.filter(function(item){return item._id === 68917;})[0].Distance = 4.5;
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aVBx8/